# check for an url in json string

Tags: java, android, json

I have below json stored in `sharedPref` as a single line string

```
[
   {
      "url":"http:\/\/google.com",
      "feedType":"Automotive"
   },
   {
      "url":"http:\/\/google.com",
      "feedType":"Automotive"
   }
]
```

I am checking that url is already present in json string using below code but its not working since `json` is escaped with `\` backslash.

```
String url = "http://google.com";
String jsonString = '[{"url":"http:\/\/google.com","feedType":"Automotive"},{"url":"http:\/\/google.com","feedType":"Automotive"}]';

if(jsonString.contains(url)) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "URL already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return false;
}
```

Please help how can i check that url is already exist in string to avoid dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will ignore the backslashes when comparing the Strings:

```
String url = "http://google.com";
String jsonString = //get it from SharedPreferences

if(jsonString.replace("\\", "").contains(url)) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "URL already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Note the use of `replace("\\", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

I've got 2 solution in mind.

First, the hard one, is to remove escape characters by deserializing your json string into objects and then compare `url`.

Second one is to remove escape characters by yourself.

Comment: ya as @JohnasCz said, I think first one is good for simplicity, it will be overkill to go an loop every object and check the it has the url :)

Comment: Choose that suits best to your app :)